# How to iterate through two lists

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm fairly new to python and am trying to create a small program, but don't know where to start. I have two lists.

```
legs = ["2", "Four", "8"] 
animals = ["Kangaroo", "Lion", "Spider"]
```

I'm trying to print the first item in the list and then ask the user to respond with how many legs the animal has. If they are wrong it will re-ask the same question, but if the user is right it will say "correct" and move to the next animal.

Any suggestions on how to go about this. I've attempt a for in loop however, I cant seem to get it to repeat if its wrong. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `I've attempt a for in loop however`. Please show us this attempt. Also the question in the title and body don't match: you say that you have problem with re-asking, not with iterating.

Comment: Post your code here and we can point out the mistake.

Comment: put an answer for you, it's not perfect but will get you started, i have been learning python3 for 2 days but its a start for you

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning python 2 days this is what i came up with

```
legs = ["2", "Four", "8"] 
animals = ["Kangaroo", "Lion", "Spider"]


for animal, leg in zip(animals, legs):
    successful = False
    while not successful:
        q = input(f"How Many Legs Does A {animal} Have? ").format(animal)

        if q == leg:
            print("Correct")
            successful = True
        else:
            print('wrong')
            successful = False
```